# Await a request to the controller from another controller - ASP .NET Core

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I have an app `LocalApp` with an API-Controller `MyController_A`.

When somebody sends a request to `MyController_A`, the controller redirects the request to a different application `RemoteApp` and pauses.

When the `RemoteApp` has done with calculations, it sends a post request to the `LocalApp`, to a different controller `MyController_B`.

The task is to await a post request inside `MyController_A` from the `MyController_B` before sending a response.

The example below could help to clarify the problem:

```cs
public class MyController_A : ControllerBase
{
    public object Post([FromBody] MyModel message)
    {
        SendDataToAnotherApp(message);

        object result = new Task<object>(() => 
        {
            // Listening requests to MyController_B

            return request;

        }).Result;

        return result;
    }
}
```

Comment: @mortb, thanks for recomendation. I will do refactor as soon as I find a way to make it work with the remote app :)

Comment: The request your remote app does has nothing to do with the original request to your application. So you just need to make sure that the remote app only answers once the request to B is also done.

Comment: Ah now I see, remote app does a call back to Controller_B

Comment: @mortb, exactly. So I found a way, as I posted below. Maybe not the best one, but it works.

Comment: Does the callback include some id? otherwise multiple simultaneous callbacks may trigger the wrong response

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe you should redesign you architecture and not keep your controller active waiting for the other call to return.

Keep in mind that the HTTP requests have limited time and once they close, the threads inside will die.

I don't know if it is ideal for your occasion but I would recommend to use signalr to send the data to your client via web sockets when the second controller finish the job.

[aspnet/signalr](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/signalr/introduction?view=aspnetcore-3.1)

Comment: Thanks for answer. The problem is only the RemoteApp. Its architecture strongly restricts my possibilities :)

Comment: But I'll try to redesign it with SignalR!

Comment: :) I am sure you will be very satisfied :D

Answer (score 0):

You can use async/await for your Controller A

```
public class MyController_A : ControllerBase
{
    public async Task<object> Post([FromBody] MyModel message)
    {
        return await SendDataToAnotherApp(message);
    }
}
```

Comment: No, it does not answer my question.

Comment: OP is asking how he can await at (A/Index) if the response is coming to different controller actions(B/Index).

Comment: If you're saying from ControllerA.Index(), you call ControllerB.Index(). That's just wrong, and dont do that. Instead, create a service (CommonService.cs) and inject it into both controllers.

Comment: @Alex-TinLe, thanks for answer. I'll do it later, as soon as I find out, how to catch the other request

Answer (score 0):

So, maybe not the best solution, but it works.

I saved the request to the `MyController_B` inside the HttpContext.Session and getting its value from `MyController_A`.

```cs
public class MyController_B : ControllerBase {
    public void Post([FromBody] string message)
    {
        HttpContext.Session.SetString("MyController_B_request", message);
    }
}

public class MyController_A : ControllerBase
{
    public object Post([FromBody] MyModel message)
    {
        SendDataToAnotherApp(message);

        object result = new Task<object>(() => 
        {
            string request;
            while (true)
            {
                request = HttpContext.Session.GetString("MyController_B_request");
                if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(request))
                    break;

                Task.Delay(1000).Wait();
            }

            return request;

        }).Result;

        return result;
    }
}
```

Comment: Whats the point of newing up a Task and awaiting on it in a blocking way? Also this is a pretty... bad way doing things. If user runs two requests you have no idea which one will be inside the session

Comment: Or if its an web application (even if its not but in your control you can use singalR C# client on the application doing the first call), end the first request after calling external and use SignalR to notify the browser that the operation has been finished so your web app can initiate a 2nd request to obtain the result rather than blocking the connection all the time

Comment: @Tseng, thanks for you comment! Blocking task is not for real use. It was actually a separate method, but to make the post more compact, I pack it into a task.

Comment: I haven't used SignalR before, but sounds like a right thing. I'll try it!

Comment: Starting a Task and awaiting it (in a blocking manner) still makes no sense. What are you expecting it to do? You are effectively blocking **two threads**, instead of one if you would just have the while loop inside the action method (no Task or thread at all). And like I said, on concurrency (multiple requests by the same user) its unsafe

Comment: @Tseng, now I understand, what you mean :( I have to learn all this things. Thanks for clarifying.

Comment: Also on top if it, your code can impossibly work, did you even test it in realistic scenario? When `MyController_B` is called, its called by the remote server, so there is no session cookie. Sessions are user specific and the remote code would write to an "unnamed" session and it would never appear in the users session in the first place and your code from `MyController_A` would never complete

Comment: Well not **user specific** but **request specific** and identified by a unique key which is provided in the session cookie to be more specific. Point is the server calling back doesn't have this session cookie, neither should you share it (security concern) - even if the server could do the call with a specific cookie

Comment: @Tseng, ah ok, in this case it would only work, if I will use some shared resources, not the session. 
But it was doomed from the beginning :)